# Show full date in input for jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using jQuery UI datepicker, I have the following:

```
<input type="text" id="check_in">

$( "#check_in" ).datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  minDate: -1
});
```

When a date is chosen, the date is shown in the `input` field as `31/12/2013`. How can I make it show "31 December 2013" in the `input` field, but upon submission it is still `31/12/2013`?

Comment: in that case you will need to use a hidden input filed to hold the value `31/12/2013`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, yupp, doing that now. But how to translate `31/12/2013` to `31 December 2013`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need two inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="check_in" />
<input type="hidden" id="altfield" name="date" />
```

and to change the JS to

```
$("#check_in").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    altField: '#altfield',
    altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    minDate: -1
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2cEz/)

The hidden input will be submitted with the `dd/mm/yy` value, while the visible input will show the format you're trying to show.

Comment: In `<input type="hidden" id="altfield" name="date" />`, what if a default date `31/12/2013` is shown, is there a way to translate the `<input type="text" id="check_in" />` to `31 December 2013` too?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but once the format is set you of course have to set the datepickers date using that format, like so -> http://jsfiddle.net/W2cEz/1/